# Heroku Login timing out on Win64

Tags: heroku, git-bash, heroku-cli, heroku-toolbelt

I have installed the Heroku CLI for Win 64 platform and am using Git Bash.

When entering the command heroku login or heroku login -i the program asks for any key to be pressed to open up the browser yet the program times out and throws an error message.

$ heroku login
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\cli-ux\node_modules@oclif\errors\lib\index.js:42
throw err;
^

CLIError: timed out
at Object.error (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\cli-ux\node_modules@oclif\errors\lib\index.js:26:15)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules@heroku-cli\command\lib\login.js:27:38)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
oclif: { exit: 2 },
code: undefined
}

I have also taken the route of creating authorizations.

$ heroku authorizations:create
Creating OAuth Authorization... !
!    Invalid credentials provided.
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\cli-ux\node_modules@oclif\errors\lib\index.js:42
throw err;
^

CLIError: timed out
at Object.error (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\cli-ux\node_modules@oclif\errors\lib\index.js:26:15)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules@heroku-cli\command\lib\login.js:27:38)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
oclif: { exit: 2 },
code: undefined
}
!    Command failed: heroku login

Any advice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On windows, I must use PowerShell to login.

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku login -i or  --interactive
```

not
`heroku -i login` as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with how your local environment is set up. can you try to uninstall the CLI and re-install it again?

- Uninstall :https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#uninstall-the-heroku-cli
- Install :https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-the-heroku-cli